# Why don't we use plural "TOVOT" in New Years greeting for ketivah ve-hatimah TOVOT?

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Why don't we use plural "TOVOT" in New Years greeting for ketivah ve-hatimah (writing **and** sealing) **tovot**?

Comment: I suspect this is more of a grammatical question thn one related to religion.

Comment: As a near-native speaker of [Israeli] Hebrew, "_Ketivah va-Chatimah Tovot_" as a greeting (as opposed to saying "_Ketivah va-Chatimah_ [_Hen_] _Tovot_", "inscribing and sealing are good", as a statement of fact) sounds somehow wrong to me.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20382

Answer (score 1):

There is only one decree.

It is first written (ketivah - Rosh HaShana) and then sealed (chatimah - Yom Kippur).

Comment: No decree is mentioned in the blessing, and the the _Tovah_ is referring to the _Ketivah_ and _Chatimah_ which are.

Comment: From the text of ובספר חיים ברכה ושלום ופרנסה טובה ישועה ונחמה וגזירות טובות it seems that we get a decree in each of the above books.

Answer (score 0):

In the [*Mishneh Torah*, *Hilkhot Teshuvah* 3:6[3]](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/15.htm#6), it says

> **ו**[**ג**] ... שוקלין עוונות כל אחד ואחד מבאי העולם עם זכייותיו ביום טוב של ראש השנה:  מי שנמצא צדיק, נחתם לחיים; ומי שנמצא רשע, נחתם למיתה.  והבינוני, תולין לו עד יום הכיפורים:  אם עשה תשובה, נחתם לחיים; ואם לאו, נחתם למיתה.‏

In [Eliyahu Touger's translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911896/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Three.htm):

> ... the sins of every inhabitant of the world together with his merits are weighed on the festival of *Rosh HaShanah*. If one is found righteous, his [verdict] is sealed for life. If one is found wicked, his [verdict] is sealed for death. A *Beinoni*'s verdict remains tentative until *Yom Kippur*. If he repents, his [verdict] is sealed for life. If not, his [verdict] is sealed for death.

There are three options:

1. Being [inscribed and] sealed for life on *Rosh ha-Shanah*.
2. Being [inscribed and] sealed for death on *Rosh ha-Shanah*.
3. Being [inscribed but] not sealed [for life or death] on *Rosh ha-Shanah*, and [re-inscribed, if needed, and] sealed on *Yom Kippur*.

The blessing is for the first option to happen. "*Tovah*" is in the singular, because the inscribing and sealing of good verdict that we're hoping for is done in one action. (We're hoping for the verdict to be sealed already on *Rosh ha-Shanah*, not to be inscribed for life on *Rosh ha-Shanah*, and have to wait till *Yom Kippur* to have it sealed.) In fact, the *Mishneh Torah* only mentions one action ever being done (i.e. the sealing of the verdict).